# How to get array from another array

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I have a json array,like this:

```
 a=   {"title":"workers","data":[{"name":"tom","id":"LBJP01Z"},{"name":"bob","id":"LBJP08Z"},{"name":"bill","id":"LBJP02Z"}]},{"title":"teachers","data":[{"name":"jill","id":"LZJP01Z"},{"name":"tim","id":"LBJP03Z"},{"name":"sam","id":"LBJP07Z"}]}
```

I want get results like this:

```
tom
bob
bill
jill
tim
sam
```

My code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [a count]-1; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < [a[i] count]-1; j++)
    {

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[a objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);

    }
}
```

But in the end,I get results like this:

```
tom
tom
tom
tom
tom
tom
```

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then you will be better able to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

From your JSON, `a` is a dictionary, not an array. Get the `data` array to start:

```
NSArray *dataArray = a[@"data"];
```

Now, use KVC to extract the names:

```
NSArray *names = [dataArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourdict = [a JSONValue];
NSMutableArray *my_arr = [get_news objectForKey:@"data"];
[my_arr retain];
```